# android-set onTouchListener on Service

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service

I have a `Service` in my app which detects whether the user has touched the screen or not. The problem is where should I set the `onTouchListener` to listen for the touch whenever/wherever the user touches the screen?

I know how to set this listener for a layout. But what about `Service`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how onTouchListener can help you with a service...you might wanna try some BroadcastReceiver like approach. For instance, maybe detect if the screen is turned ON or OFF?

see the intent action: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON

Comment: I want to achieve something like, if user swipes right, then perform some task. This swiping can take place anywhere,not just inside my application.

Comment: You can only do that if you're app is a HOME Launcher app..read more about android.intent.category.HOME

Answer (score -1):

This might be of help, try it out!
http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-detect-global-touch-event.html